# Please explain what does the following code mean in c#?

Tags: c#

I saw a code similar to what mentioned below :

```
public class SomeClass : AnotherClass
{
   public SomeClass();
   .
   .
   .
   .
}
```

So what is the meaning of the following line of code in this, what does it do ?

```
public SomeClass();
```

[Code I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuAU9.png).

Comment: It doesn't mean anything because it fails to compile. If the line is actually `public SomeClass() { ... }` then it's a constructor for `SomeClass`.

Comment: It's a constructor - it's used to create a new instance of `SomeClass`.  You might want to google for some basic C# tutorials, as this and many other concepts will be explained.

Comment: I think you meant public SomeClass() {} ?

Comment: public SomeClass() is constructor function of class

Comment: That is the class's constructor, it is the first method executed when the class is created. Downvoted because it appears that there was zero research effort by OP.

Comment: but a constructor generally looks like this-  public SomeClass() { ... }              and the syntax here looks different, also it is followed by a semicolon. Is it different from a regular constructor ?

Comment: If this is a constructor why is it having a different syntax, is it a different kind of constructor ? And if it's a constructor unlike a regular constructors why is it followed by a semicolon ?

Comment: @Nik Since everyone in this thread is saying that it's a constructor (and I don't see anyone who said different).. would be a hint that the example of code you provided has some syntax errors for properly declaring a default constructor.. what you provided would not compile..

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Now i have provided the screen shot of actual code and it is from C# library class, hope there are no syntax errors in that.

Comment: @Nik did you retrieve the code for that class by using *Go To Definition*?  If so, it is only going to show you declarations and not implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referencing is called a **Constructor**.  Constructors have the same name as the class, and they are used to initialize data members of the new object.

Please [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

> Whenever a class or struct is created, its constructor is called. A class or struct may have multiple constructors that take different arguments. Constructors enable the programmer to set default values, limit instantiation, and write code that is flexible and easy to read.

If you saw code similar to what you mentioned, then honestly that would cause a compile time error, since the syntax for that default constructor (taking 0 parameters) is incorrect.

Needs to be:

```
public SomeClass()
{
    //initialize members;
}
```

If you retrieved the code that you just posted a picture of, by hitting *Go To Definition* of the class, then it will only show declarations, and not implementation.

Comment: Yes GTown-Coder, i retrieved the code by hitting Go To Definition

Answer (score 3):

that is the constructor of the class **SomeClass**, and you can use it (call it) everytime you need to create a new object (AKA instance) of the class **SomeClass**

take a look at [how to use a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) (Thanks to [CrowCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276469/crowcoder) for the comment) and if required take a look at the constructors [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

> Instance constructors are used to create and initialize any instance
>   member variables when you use the new expression to create an object
>   of a class. To initialize a static class, or static variables in a
>   non-static class, you must define a static constructor. For more
>   information, see Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide).

Comment: I don't think this is a good explanation at all for someone this inexperienced. For one thing it implies you can call a constructor like any other method, and the link, imo, should [point to this page instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for the suggest, i will include that in the post...